# If statements with masked arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, mask

I am trying to run a (nested conditions) program using masked arrays. I have used the same function with no masked arrays and works fine. The function looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.random.rand(100)
x = x.reshape(4,25)
x = np.ma.masked_less(x,0.2) 
y = np.random.rand(100)
y = y.reshape(4,25)
y = np.ma.masked_less(y,0.2)
z = np.zeros_like(x)

#say that both arrays are masked in the same positions.

for i in range(len(x)):
    for j in range(len(y)):
        if x[i,j] >= y[i,j]:
            if (x[i,j]-y[i,j]) > (z[i,j-1]):
               z[i,j] = 0.
            else:
               z[i,j] = 1.
        else:
            z[i,j] = z[i,j-1] - (x[i,j]-y[i,j])
```

I do expect to get an array with the same characteristics (i.e.masked as well) of input data (x,y in this case). However, the results I am getting are, or a totally masked array, or one filled with values without mask as I show here:

```
z = 
masked_array(data =
[[-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
[-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
[-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
..., 
[-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
[-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
[-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]],
         mask =
[[ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
[ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
[ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
..., 
[ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
[ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
[ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]],
   fill_value = 9.96920996839e+36)

z = 
masked_array(data =
[[9.0 9.0 9.0 ..., 9.0 9.0 9.0]
[9.0 9.0 9.0 ..., 9.0 9.0 9.0]
[9.0 9.0 9.0 ..., 9.0 9.0 9.0]
..., 
[9.0 9.0 9.0 ..., 9.0 9.0 9.0]
[9.0 9.0 9.0 ..., 9.0 9.0 9.0]
[9.0 9.0 9.0 ..., 9.0 9.0 9.0]],
         mask =
[[False False False ..., False False False]
[False False False ..., False False False]
[False False False ..., False False False]
..., 
[False False False ..., False False False]
[False False False ..., False False False]
[False False False ..., False False False]],
   fill_value = 9.96920996839e+36)
```

when actually I want something like this:

```
z = 
masked_array(data =
[[9.0 -- -- ..., -- -- --]
[8.7 -- -- ..., -- -- --]
[-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
..., 
[1.0 -- -- ..., -- -- --]
[-- 3.6 -- ..., -- -- --]
[-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]],
         mask =
[[ False  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
[ False  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
[ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
..., 
[ False  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
[ True  False  True ...,  True  True  True]
[ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]],
   fill_value = 9.96920996839e+36)
```

I have read the information available about masked arrays, as well as  similar questions here, but none of them have a satisfactory explanation on this. I was wondering if it could be possible that conditional statements work in a similar way of numpy.where in the sense that they show only the indices of such conditions?

Comment: How do you use `x[i,j]` with an array that has shape `(100,)`?

Comment: @hpaulj I am sorry, I just forgot adding that I reshaped the array, so after `x = np.random.rand(100)`, I have `x = x.reshape(4,25)`. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another way of doing the computations, without masking the arrays. 
If you want, you still can mask the `z` array in the end.

```
    x = np.random.rand(100)
    x = x.reshape(4,25)
    y = np.random.rand(100)
    y = y.reshape(4,25)

    # first if- first if
    idxs_1 = ( x >= y) & ((x-y) > (z-1)) 
    z[idxs_1] = 0

    # second if-else
    idxs_2 = (x>=y) & ((x-y) <= z-1)
    z[idxs_2] = 1

    # final else
    idxs_3 = x < y 
    idxs_3_p = np.hstack((idxs_3[:, 1:], idxs_3[:,0][:,None])) # reshape so that we shift z by one column left        

    z[idxs_3] = z[idxs_3_p] - (x[idxs_3] - y[idxs_3])
```

You will need to double-check the correctness of the boolean indexing on some test data.

Comment: Thank you very much. I really appreciate your response. I think I am in the way to solve my issues by writing the function with a single 'internal' loop and using 'external' loops to run it with 2 and 3D arrays. Currently, I am testing my function with actual data. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

1. there is probably a typo in the second `if`-statement. It should be

   ```
   for i in range(len(x)):
       for j in range(len(y)):
           if x[i,j] >= y[i,j]:
               if (x[i,j]-y[i,j]) > (z[i,j-1]): # not x - y[i,j], but x[i,j]-y[i,j] ??
                   # and further down
   ```
2. On my computer, it actually works and produces the expected results, i.e., the masked array with masked/unmasked mixed together:

   ```
    In [2]: z
    Out[2]: 
    masked_array(data =
     [[0.34864202355178786 1.0 1.0 1.6118423555903627 -- 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
      0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0]
     [0.32457641778594915 1.0 1.0 -- -- 0.0 -- 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
      0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0]
     [-- 1.0 1.541983077540757 1.0 0.0 0.0 -- 0.0 0.0 0.0 -- 0.0 0.0 -- 0.0 0.0
      0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 -- 0.0 0.0 --]
     [-- -- 1.0 -- 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 -- 0.0 -- 0.0 0.0 0.0 -- 0.0 -- 0.0 --
      -- 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0]],
                 mask =
     [[False False False False  True False False False False False False False
      False False False False False False False False False False False False
      False]
     [False False False  True  True False  True False False False False False
      False False False False False False False False False False False False
      False]
     [ True False False False False False  True False False False  True False
      False  True False False False False False False False  True False False
       True]
     [ True  True False  True False False False False False  True False  True
      False False False  True False  True False  True  True False False False
      False]],
           fill_value = 1e+20)
   ```

Comment: @pausang. Thank you very much for your insight, but actually it is a mistake I have here. My actual code has this point fine, otherwise I will get the value error `The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`. Also, the actual masked arrays I am using are netCDF files, which we use in atmospheric and oceanic sciences.  I am still trying to debugging my code, but thank you very much for mentioning this.  PS. I have tried running the example I showed here and it works as well.

Comment: So, I suppose, there might be a problem in the input data. If you tell more about the problem, I might try to help.

Comment: Thank you very much. The only thing I am doing to the input data before running the program is reshaping them into 2D arrays (since they are originally 3D arrays netCDF files). Then, I multiply both files by 0.0393700787 to convert millimeters to inches unit. Also, given that the files are fairly large (shapes (1300,360,720)), I selected those in my target area with numpy where. So, their shapes are now (1300, 52, 130) with the axis = 1 and 2 representing latitude and longitude respectively.

Comment: The files are indeed large for the for-cycle to be slow. However, you could still stick to the the numpy machinery to do everything without the masked arrays. See the answer below how to do it with numpy. Hope it helps. I personally tried to do masked arrays a few times and finally gave up (I did some 2D and 3D numerical integration)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem by using an 'external' loop. By this I mean that I used only a single loop in my core function instead of 2 or 3 depending on my data (1D to 3D arrays), i.e.

```
def func(x,y):
    import numpy as np
    x = np.random.rand(100)
    x = x.reshape(4,25)
    x = np.ma.masked_less(x,0.2) 
    y = np.random.rand(100)
    y = y.reshape(4,25)
    y = np.ma.masked_less(y,0.2)
    z = np.zeros_like(x)

#say that both arrays are masked in the same positions.

    for i in range(len(x)):
        z[i] =  x[i] >= y[i]:
            if (x[i]-y[i]) > (z[i-1]):
               z[i] = 0.
            else:
               z[i] = 1.
        else:
            z[i] = z[i-1] - (x[i]-y[i])

return z
```

Then, if I have, say a 3D array netCDF file, I apply my function as:

```
func = np.zeros_like(x)
for i in range(len(x)):
    for j in range(len(y)):
        func[i,j] = func(x[i,j],x[i,j])
```

Please note that using numpy.where is a good and faster option as well. However, with my short experience in python (and programing in general), I am not taking advantage in the numpy machinery to vectorize my function. For now, my function seems to work as I expected.